# How to get the second last element of a list in C++

Tags: c++

i just started programing in C++, and have a little bit of experience in C, but in this program was trying to use the C++ libraries that i am not familiar to at all.

The objective of the program is simple, i have a linked list and i need to get the second to last element of the list. What i did was reversing the list, using the reverse function, and then i was trying to get the new second element of the list, using std::next, because this would be the element i wanted. But i am unable to then print object, since it either print the pointer value or when i deference it says that std:cout is not able to print it because it does not know how to convert the value. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <list>

#define LOG(x) std::cout << x << std::endl;

typedef std::list<int> list;

list *getNextXValue(list *Head, int x)
{
    return std::next(Head, x);
}

/**
 * @brief Find last element of a linked list of ints
 *
 * @return int Program ended correctly
 */
int main()
{
    list listOne;
    list *aux = NULL;

    // Inserts all the elements in the list
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        listOne.insert(listOne.end(), i);
    }

    listOne.reverse();

    aux = getNextXValue(&listOne, 1);

    LOG(*aux);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is 'C+++' ?

Comment: std::list is bidirectional so just iterate backwards. I think you confused list with std::forward_list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i was trying to get the new second element of the list, using std::next.

You are not getting the new second element of the list, what you are trying to get is the next **new address** of the list, since what you are passing is the pointer, the address of the list, not the iterator:

```cpp
list *getNextXValue(list *Head, int x)
{
    return std::next(Head, x);
}
```

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

#define LOG(x) std::cout << x << std::endl;

typedef std::list<int> list;

std::list<int>::iterator getNextXValue(std::list<int>::iterator Head, int x) {
  return std::next(Head, x);
}

/**
 * @brief Find last element of a linked list of ints
 *
 * @return int Program ended correctly
 */
int main() {
  list listOne;
  list *aux = NULL;

  // Inserts all the elements in the list
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    listOne.insert(listOne.end(), i);
  }

  listOne.reverse();

  auto next = getNextXValue(listOne.begin(), 1);

  std::cout << *next << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, that did it, it is now working, I will now continue on this journey to know C++ better

Comment: If it works, you could mark this problem as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:
`std::list<int> l = {1, 2, 3}; // (types shouldn't matter), you can do *std::prev(l.end(), 2);`